# Setting up HTTPS connection in Windows Phone (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, ssl, https

Is there a VB.NET class for setting up secure connections with a server? I'm looking for something similar to the `HTTPSUrlConnection` class for Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Android class you mention but if you're trying to make a connection over SSL/HTTPS you just make it the same way as one over HTTP. No special classes required.

Comment: So you mean I simply need to enter an HTTPS url?

Comment: @user1301428 Yep. As long as the certificate the site uses if from a supported Root Certificate provider http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14215.windows-and-windows-phone-8-ssl-root-certificate-program-member-cas.aspx